# Have different sessions in flask for a chatbot with langchain

Tags: python, flask, chatbot, openai-api, langchain

I created a chatbot on a flask server using RetrievalQA.from_chain_type where I had no problems with sessions, only I had to make some changes and implement a memory that takes into account the conversation a user is having, but on this part I am having problems on how to handle them with different sessions

```
@app.route('/answer', methods=['POST'])
def answer():
template = """
Use the following context (delimited by <ctx></ctx>) and the chat history (delimited by <hs></hs>) to answer the question:
------
<ctx>
{context}
</ctx>
------
<hs>
{history}
</hs>
------
{question}
Answer:
"""
prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["history", "context", "question"],
    template=template,
)
CHROMA_SETTINGS = Settings(
    chroma_db_impl='duckdb+parquet',
    persist_directory='db',
    anonymized_telemetry=False)
db = Chroma(persist_directory='db', embedding_function=embeddings, client_settings=CHROMA_SETTINGS)
retriever = db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": target_source_chunks})   
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm=ChatOpenAI(),
        chain_type='stuff',
        retriever=retriever,
        verbose=True,
        chain_type_kwargs={
            "verbose": True,
            "prompt": prompt,
            "memory": ConversationBufferMemory(
                memory_key="history",
                input_key="question"),
        }
    )         
query = request.form['query']
result = qa.run({'query': query})

return jsonify({'answer': result})`
```

this is the code I was trying to implement, only every time a question comes to the chatbot it practically reinstantiates the objects present and it practically deletes the conversations, I tried keeping in session qa but without success, what could I try?

Comment: https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-sessions/

Comment: what I had tried to do was to keep the qa object in session, but the error I was getting:
TypeError: cannot pickle 'duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection' object

, before implementing the history I had no problem, I wouldn't know how to structure it

Comment: my idea was to keep the chat_history in session, I just wouldn't know how to structure it, either create a vector that I pass to the buffermemory, or pass from the 
RetrievalQA.from_chain_type to the ConversationalRetrievalChain

Comment: Not all data can be pickled - as in this .. I've not really used pickle (and its used under the hood).. Maybe using "dill" module could help in this case ? https://realpython.com/python-pickle-module/#picklable-and-unpicklable-types covers some approaches